# CSS height is different in different browser

Tags: css

The height of the blue bar in Safari and Chrome matches but in Firefox it is smaller. I would like to make them equal.

Comment: How do you detect the different height between different browser? It looks like you set the fixed height of your header.

Comment: Yes I did. I opened the sites in all browsers and just putted them next to each other on my screen.

Comment: need to have some code

Comment: There was the website link but I removed.  hexerei answered my question. Anyways thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a css hack for firefox:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() { 
  header {
     height:50px; /* or whatever fits best there */
  }
}
```

This should only be interpreted by Firefox, while Opera, Chrome and Safari will use the default `header {...}` definition